# Post file like .jpg or .pdf to third party API using vb.net web application

Tags: vb.net, http-post

Want to post file to third party API as "contents" parameter. Have written below code but server return **400 Bad Request** error. Can any one help me find the solution? The same is working from postman. Below is the code for reference:

```
Dim req As WebRequest

    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim fileLocation As String = Server.MapPath("..\Uploads\Docs\" + fileName)
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation)

    Dim length As Long = 0

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

    req = WebRequest.Create(url)
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", key)
    req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    'req.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length

    Dim boundary As String = "---------------------------" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary

    Dim boundaryBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbCrLf & "--" & boundary & vbCrLf)
    Dim endBoundaryBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbCrLf & "--" & boundary & "--" & vbCrLf)

    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(fileLocation)

    Using requestStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        ' Write the start boundary
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length)

        ' Write the file data
        Dim fileHeader = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""contents""; filename=""" & Path.GetFileName(fileLocation) & """" & vbCrLf & "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Dim fileHeaderBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileHeader)
        requestStream.Write(fileHeaderBytes, 0, fileHeaderBytes.Length)
        requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)

        ' Write the end boundary
        requestStream.Write(endBoundaryBytes, 0, endBoundaryBytes.Length)
    End Using

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

I want to send request as "contents: file_to_upload". From postman it is working fine.. below is the screenshot for reference:

[image]